# regex.replace - not finding my pattern?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find a guid within an xml string starting with adid=

So the string I'm trying to pull out of an xml string is adid=[guid]

The guid is an 8 digit hex, 4 digit hex, 4 digit hex, 4 digit hex, and 12 digit hex, separated by dashes, for instance, the one within my test string is adId=38d96c20-2515-41b4-a181-15588e3d7c1e

I'm new to using Regex, so I wouldn't be surprise if it's something fundamental.

Here is my code:

```
var adid = Regex.Replace(xmlString,
                         @"adid=[A-F0-9]{8}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{12}",
                         "$&",
                         RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

//adid is now the same string as xmlString
```

What am I doing wrong?

input:

> fawetreawfafadidadid=38d96c20-2515-41b4-a181-15588e3d7c1e1231d21d12f1g

should return: adid=38d96c20-2515-41b4-a181-15588e3d7c1e

Comment: Can you post your input xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"$&" in replacement string means "match from the source string" - so you are essentially replacing found substring with itself. See [Substitutions in Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> *$&* Includes a copy of the entire match in the replacement string

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but

- consider using XML api to parse XML first
- if you want to insert `&` by hand in XML make sure it is encoded correctly
- you may need to escape `$` in replace pattern `$$`.

Sample producing *invalid xml*:

```
var adid = Regex.Replace(xmlString,
    @"[A-F0-9]{8}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{4}-[A-F0-9]{12}",
   "$$&", // notice "$$" for escaped "$"
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to guarantee `adid=` is before the guid you'll need a positive look-behind:

```
string test =  Regex.Replace("aslkjfhasdfkasdadId=38d96c20-2515-42b4-a181-15588e3d7c1e",
                     @"(?<=adid=)[A-F\d]{8}-[A-F\d]{4}-[A-F\d]{4}-[A-F\d]{4}-[A-F\d]{12}",
                     "",
                     RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Yea the fact that I'm not even finding the guid itself has kept me from even trying to add the adid part

Comment: Alexei found your main problem.  Combine that Regex with his solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Regex.Replace(xmlString, 
              @"^(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}$, 
              "'$0'", 
              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I actually started with that and it didn't work so I tried my own.

Comment: @user2081737 changed the answer to better reflect what you need. did not put adid in though....

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is supposed to be the result, but if you want to have a string

adid=[guid] - then your code will look like this:

```
Regex.Replace(xmlString, 
              @"\b[A-F0-9]{8}(?:-[A-F0-9]{4}){3}-[A-F0-9]{12}\b", 
              "[guid]", 
              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

If you want to get only the guid, then you don´t need replace

```
Regex.Match(xmlString, 
              @"\b[A-F0-9]{8}(?:-[A-F0-9]{4}){3}-[A-F0-9]{12}\b", 
              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

For testing regular expressions I recommend using this software: http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/ It is free and simple.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

```
adId=[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}
```

If you don't want the adId= part then remove it.

Comment: I tested with: adId=[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{12} using the notepad++ regex plugin.

Comment: GUID is list of hexadecimal numbers. G-Z characters are not valid.

Comment: I fixed it so now it goes a through f. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
[RexFiddle](http://www.rexfiddle.net/WVQqQNI)

`\S{8}-\S{4}-\S{4}-\S{4}-\S{12}`

Comment: that could end up matching non guids if he were unfortunate